# Masking the url when using Google Analytics Experiments for A/B Testing

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

I am trying out Google Analytics Experiments as a way to setup and A/B test some landing pages. 
http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1745147

Is there a way to mask the URL that shows up as a result of the redirect to one of the pages?

Experiments looks like a great feature in analytics, especially since it is so well integrated with the rest of the analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You can "set" the page if you have events on the page too

```
_gaq.push(["_set", "page", "/custom/page/path.html"]); // sets page for all future
```

or just add a second parameter to track pageview

```
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "/custom/page/path.html"]); // just custom pageview path
```